# Pinterest Wordpress Plugin Display Image

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am currently trying to create a plugin using Pinterest for Wordpress. I have ran into a slight problem, I've been trying to return an image with a link but only been able to only return a link.

```
<?php

function displayPinterest()
{
    $request = wp_remote_get( 'https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/mercurizen/shoeswatches/pins/?access_token=AXgIMQmjCFDXyJsHni0wYUdZxshcFETISS1nfSRDAz1G7WBDJgAAAAA&fields=image,note,link&limit=5' );
    $pins = json_decode( $request['body'], true );
    if( !empty( $pins['data'] ) ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach( $pins['data'] as $pin ) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . $pin['url'] . '">' . $pin['note']. '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

}
?>
```

Anyone experienced with Wordpress Plugins and Pinterest can help me with this problem ?

Comment: https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/mercurizen/shoeswatches/pins/?access_token=AXgIMQmjCFDXyJsHni0wYUdZxshcFETISS1nfSRDAz1G7WBDJgAAAAA&limit=5 API itself doesn't give images in response.

Comment: @Milap , sorry I updated the API link

Comment: Please update link in your question, its still old one.

Comment: @Milap There we go it should of updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your code as below. You will get text in `$pin['note']` and image url in `$img['url']`.

```
function displayPinterest()
{
    $request = wp_remote_get( 'https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/mercurizen/shoeswatches/pins/?access_token=AXgIMQmjCFDXyJsHni0wYUdZxshcFETISS1nfSRDAz1G7WBDJgAAAAA&fields=image,note,link&limit=5' );

    $pins = json_decode( $request, true );
    if( !empty( $pins['data'] ) ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach( $pins['data'] as $pin ) {
            $img = $pin['image']['original'];
            echo '<li><a href="' . $img['url'] . '">' . $pin['note']. '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually get an error "Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string"

Comment: @ryuuman123 , my code is working for me. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/esbx-ak24 Checkout.

Comment: it didn't work for me, i ended up changing most of the code